# The value of the local or argument 'e' is unobtainable at this time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 project I have the following code:

```
    private void FromBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (VirtualKey.Decimal == e.Key)
        {
            if (true == FromBox.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

and it tells me that:

> "The value of the local or argument 'e' is unobtainable at this time."

I press the decimal button on the numpad and it will obviously work, but somehow it skips the if clause because of this..

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is "it" in "it tells me that"?

Comment: Try restarting Visual Studio or making sure you're building agains't the right target framework.

Comment: It is a debugger notification.  Rebuild the project, ensure you are not debugging the Release build.